# An error while trying to use glm model for prediction on another computer

Tags: r, save, load, glm

I would like to save a glm object in one R machine and use it for prediction on another data set located on another machine that has a newer data.I try to use `save` and `load` but with no success.What am I doing wrong?
Here is a toy example:

```
# on machine 1:
glm<-glm(y~x1+x2,data=dat1, family=binomial(link="logit")
save(glm,file="glm.Rdata") # the file is stored in a folder.

# on machine 2:
load(glm.RData) # got an error:"Error in load(glm.RData) : object 'glm.RData' not found"
#I tried :
 load(file='glm.RData') # no error was displayed
  print(glm) # got an error:"Error in load(glm.RData) : object 'glm.RData' not found"
```

Any help will be great.

Comment: Are you in the correct workspace? You can use `load(file.choose())` to navigate to the correct file.

Comment: You may want to look at `?getwd` and `?setwd`.

Comment: I followed @Pascal  comments and I saw that the size of the glm file is huge 0.5GB. Shouldn't it be a small fie that contains only the formula?

Comment: `str(glm)` will give you a glimpse of what is stored inside. And I would avoid `glm` as name, as it is the function itself.

Comment: I loaded the file,and it works! Thanks for your help. However I don't really understand if there is a way to save only the model's forumla and not the whole data set with it?

Comment: You might be interested in `bigglm` from package biglm.

Answer (score 0):

As per @user3710546's advice, I would avoid saving your model using the name `glm`, as it'll mask (ie. block) the `glm()` function, making it difficult for you to use it in your session.

## Using `save()` and `load()`

[`save()`](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.3.1/topics/save) is generally used to save a *list* of objects to a file, rather than a single object. The first argument to [`save()`](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.3.1/topics/save) is `list`, 'A character vector containing the *names* of objects to be saved.'  (Emphasis mine.) So you'd want to use it like this:

```
# On machine 1:
save(list = 'glm', file = '/path/to/glm.RData')

# On machine 2:
load(file = '/path/to/glm.RData')
```

**Note that the file extensions are often case-sensitive: you saved to a file with the extension `.RData` but loaded from one with the extension `.Rdata`, which is different. This may explain why the file isn't found.**

## Using `saveRDS()` and `readRDS()`

An alternative to using `save()` and `load` is to use [`saveRDS()`](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.3.1/topics/readRDS) and [`readRDS()`](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.3.1/topics/readRDS), which are designed to be used with one object. They're used slightly differently:

```
# On machine 1
saveRDS(glm, file = '/path/to/glm.rds')

# On machine 2
glm = readRDS(file = '/path/to/glm.rds')
```

Note the `.rds` file extension and the fact that `readRDS()` isn't automatically put in the environment (it needs to be assigned to something).

## Saving parts of a GLM

If you just want the formula saved—that is, the actual text string—you can find it in `glm$formula`, where `glm` is the name of your object. It comes back as a `formula` object, but you can convert it to a string with `as.character(glm$formula)`, to then be written to a text file or whatever.

If, however, you want the model *itself* without the dataset it was created from (to cut down on disk space), have a look at [this article](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2014/05/trimming-the-fat-from-glm-models-in-r), which discusses which parts of a `glm` object can be safely deleted.